# SQL CONTAINSTABLE - Unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains, stop-words

I have a table programs with some records and have a different results if using LIKE or CONTAINSTABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE Programs (
    ID varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

Insert INTO Programs VALUES 
('1', '5 Horas em Islamabad'), 
('2','Gus Melhoras" Melhora'), 
('3', '13 Horas - Os Soldados Secretos de Benghazi'),
('4','72 Horas de Medo'), 
('5','As Primeiras 48 Horas')

SELECT distinct Title FROM Programs WHERE Title LIKE '%Horas%'

SELECT ID, Title, KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM Programs AS DocTable   
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Programs, Title, 'Horas') AS KEY_TBL  
  ON DocTable.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK > 0  
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC;
```

With **LIKE** i have 5 results

```
ID  Title
1   5 Horas em Islamabad
2   Gus Melhoras" Melhora
3   13 Horas - Os Soldados Secretos de Benghazi
4   72 Horas de Medo
5   As Primeiras 48 Horas
```

With **ContainsTable** i have 2 results

```
ID  Title                   RANK
4   72 Horas de Medo        32
5   As Primeiras 48 Horas   32
```

I understand why the record with title "Gus Melhoras" Melhora" is not returned, because does not have the word "Horas".
But the records "5 Horas em Islamabad" and "13 Horas - Os Soldados Secretos de Benghazi" contain the word "Horas" and do not return.

Can anybody why this happened and can help me?

My dbms are Microsoft SQL Server.

[Columns used in Full text index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYsDU.png)

**EDIT**:

In my case i defined the "Language for Word Breaker" in "Brazilian". If i changed to "English" returns correctly 4 items.

The word i search "Horas" is "Hours" in English. But if i add the new record, with title "13 hours in Islamabad" and search by word "Hours" the record is returned.

Anyone know why this particular behavior in Brazilian or Portuguese Language?

More, in Spanish "Horas" is the same word "Horas" and if i change my "Language for Word Breaker" to Spanish the 4 items are returned.

**EDIT2**:

Used the queries send by @Randy in Marin and i did the test used the Portuguese language.

```
SELECT s.stopword, l.name 
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords s 
JOIN sys.fulltext_languages l ON l.lcid = s.language_id 
WHERE l.lcid = 2070 -- portuguese
```

```
stopword    name
0   Portuguese
1   Portuguese
2   Portuguese
3   Portuguese
4   Portuguese
5   Portuguese
6   Portuguese
7   Portuguese
8   Portuguese
9   Portuguese
a   Portuguese
agora   Portuguese
...
```

When execute the query to find the exact matches

```
SELECT occurrence, special_term, left(display_term, 20) as [display_term] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"5 Horas em Islamabad"', 2070, 0, 0); -- portuguese
```

```
occurrence  special_term    display_term
1   Exact Match tt24050000
1   Exact Match 5 horas
1   Exact Match tt24170000
2   Noise Word  em
3   Exact Match islamabad
```

It's the equal result to the Brazilian language, although there are digits stopwords

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That functionality is product specific.)

Comment: which columns you have full text index on?

Comment: i'm using sql server.

Comment: the columns are Id and Title

Comment: I created your table and created a full text index.  I get 4 records.  Perhaps you can recreate the full text index and see if it changes the results.

Comment: Hi @RandyinMarin. I think know why in your case return 4 items. The "Language for Word Breaker" in your case are "English"?

Comment: In my case i defined the "Language for Word Breaker" in "Brazilian". If i changed to "English" returns correctly 4 items.

The word i search "Horas" is "Hours" in English. But if i add the new record, with title "13 hours in Islamabad" and search by word "Hours" the record is returned.

Anyone know why this particular behavior in Brazilian or Portuguese Language?

More, in Spanish "Horas" is the same word "Horas" and if i change my "Language for Word Breaker" to Spanish the 4 items are returned. Do you understand why?

Comment: The fulltext index on the table will be for one language. Perhaps you need one table per language or a view per language on one table. Then the fulltext index can be the correct language on either the specific table or the view for the language. It will be one search per language. I still don't expect the same result for the same untranslated phrase in all languages.

Answer (score 0):

The dmv sys.dm_fts_parser shows how a phrase is parsed for different languages with or without a stoplist or accent.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

--select * from sys.syslanguages

SELECT occurrence, special_term, left(display_term, 20) as [display_term] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"5 Horas em Islamabad"', 1033, 0, 0); -- english

SELECT occurrence, special_term, left(display_term, 20) as [display_term] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"5 Horas em Islamabad"', 1046, 0, 0); -- brazilian

SELECT occurrence, special_term, left(display_term, 20) as [display_term] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"5 Horas em Islamabad"', 3082, 0, 0); -- spanish

occurrence  special_term     display_term
----------- ---------------- --------------------
1           Noise Word       5
1           Noise Word       nn5
2           Exact Match      horas
3           Exact Match      em
4           Exact Match      islamabad

occurrence  special_term     display_term
----------- ---------------- --------------------
1           Exact Match      tt24050000
1           Exact Match      5 horas
1           Exact Match      tt24170000
2           Noise Word       em
3           Exact Match      islamabad

occurrence  special_term     display_term
----------- ---------------- --------------------
1           Noise Word       5
1           Noise Word       nn5
2           Exact Match      horas
3           Exact Match      em
4           Exact Match      islamabad
```

The "5" is not a noise word in Brazilian.  I tried null for a stoplist and both 0 and 1 for the accent and it did not help.

If you run the following two queries, it's clear that the Brazialian stoplist is very different.  It does not have digits.  Perhaps it should.  Maybe a support call is required.

```
SELECT s.stopword, l.name
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords s
JOIN sys.fulltext_languages l
ON l.lcid = s.language_id
WHERE l.lcid = 1033

stopword
----------------------------------------------------------------
$
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
A
B
C
D
E
...

SELECT s.stopword, l.name
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords s
JOIN sys.fulltext_languages l
ON l.lcid = s.language_id
WHERE l.lcid = 1046

stopword
----------------------------------------------------------------
a
abaixo
acaso
aceleradamente
acerca
acima
acolá
ademais
adentro
adiantado
adiante
adrede
afora
agora
agorinha
ainda
alerta
algo
algum
alguma
algumas
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was unaware of these evaluation queries, they are very useful. With this information i tried se same select to the portuguese language.

Comment: ```SELECT s.stopword, l.name
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords s
JOIN sys.fulltext_languages l
ON l.lcid = s.language_id
WHERE l.lcid = 2070```

Comment: in portuguese exists the numeric stopwords 0,1,2,3,4...

Comment: But when execute the query ```SELECT occurrence, special_term, left(display_term, 20) as [display_term] 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"5 Horas em Islamabad"', 2070, 0, 0);```

Comment: I get the same result as using the Brazilian language ```1           Exact Match      tt24050000
1           Exact Match      5 horas
1           Exact Match      tt24170000
2           Noise Word       em
3           Exact Match      islamabad```

Comment: Sorry for a bad formatting, but i don't know how format the code in comment area

Answer (score 0):

LIKE and CONTAINSTABLE can be expected to have different results.  LIKE uses simple and deterministic pattern matching rules and all characters are significant.  CONTAINSTABLE uses a complex system that attempts to apply language specific algorithms to do fuzzy matches.

If storing documents that can be of different languages, specifying the language in CONTAINSTABLE can yield better results. The LCID might be stored in the record of the document and passed to CONTAINSTABLE in the join.  If not specified, the language of the full text is used and might not be a good match.

```
SELECT ID, Title, KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM Programs AS DocTable   
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Programs, Title, 'Horas', 1046) AS KEY_TBL  
  ON DocTable.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK > 0  
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC;
```

UPDATE:
Here is a means to check in which languages a value is a stopword.

```
select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords
WHERE stopword IN ('5', 'em')

stopword                                                         language_id
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
5                                                                0
5                                                                1028
5                                                                1030
5                                                                1031
5                                                                1033
5                                                                1036
5                                                                1040
5                                                                1041
5                                                                1043
5                                                                1045
5                                                                1049
5                                                                1053
5                                                                1054
5                                                                1055
5                                                                2052
5                                                                2057
5                                                                2070
5                                                                3082
em                                                               1046
em                                                               2070
```

Comment: I think the problem stay in language i defined in full text index. I defined my language "Brazilian" and if defined in my select containstable the language 1046, the values not returns. If in full index defined to the columns the language English independently i defined language or not in select, all values are returned.

Comment: my fear is to change the language of my columns to another language (english) and when searching for other words to have wrong results too.